# Обработка исключений на этапе импорта python 2.7, 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Есть некий код, в котором используются zip и zip_longest из itertools в обработке списков.
Проблема заключается в следующем, этот код должен работать как на Python 2.7 (знаю что уже не поддерживается), так и на 3.6.
Но для python 2.7 нет функций **zip** и **zip_longest**, но есть **izip** и **izip_longest**.Для "универсальности" импортирую функции вот таким образом:

```
# import izip_longest for python2.7:
try:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
except:
    pass

# import zip_longest for python 3.6:
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest
except:
    pass

value_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
value_2 = ["a", "b", "e"]
result = list(zip_longest(value_1, value_2))
print (result)
```

В PyCharm проверяю работоспособность кода, меняя интерпретатор - код работает.Ошибок не возникает.
Корректно ли так делать импорт?
Какие проблемы могут при этом возникнуть?

Comment: try import, вроде так

Comment: Не должно быть особых проблем. В принципе можно делать в try один вариант импорта, а в `except ImportError` (лучше указывать отлавливаемое исключение) - второй вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Я думаю что лучше будет так*

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    from itertools import zip_longest
else:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
```